# Not finding DLL When Ran as a Startup Program

Tags: c#, .net, dll

My program runs perfectly except when it is launched as a startup program. When launched as a start up program it is not able to find a first party DLL (or one of it's dependencies).

I get the following exception:

> Could not find file or assembly X or one of it's dependencies: C:\Windows\SysWow64\X.dll

It is looking for the first party DLL in the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\` directory instead of in the local directory `C:\Program Files\MyProgram\`.

The confusing part is, if I launch the program manually everything works fine.

How do I go about finding the source of this problem? I tried using Fusion Log but it only told me the same thing as the exception: That it was trying to load from `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` only.

I read that this can occur when your application uses `Assembly.Load` - The culprit program does use `Assembly.LoadFrom` - but again, this works fine except when done at start up.

Furthermore, the culprit program does have some `[DllImport]` attributes.

Comment: Always, **always**, specify the full path name of a file.  Not "baz.dll", it must be "c:\foo\bar\baz.dll".  Environment.CurrentDirectory is the worst possible global variable.  And sure, it isn't set where you hope it is when you use the Run registry key.  Use Application.StartupPath or Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location to format that path.

Comment: @HansPassant ... great answer, but now that you've put it in a comment, where does that leave the rest of us? :-) . We can either leave the question open (ugh), or put the exact same info into the answer box (ugh). Are you expecting it to be closed as duplicate?

Comment: I do not specify a path, only giving it the name of the DLL as the`Assembly.LoadFrom` documentation says it accepts a relative path. I have tried with an absolute path and this worked. Why `Assembly.LoadFrom` doesn't use the application base when the program is a start up program I do not know.

Comment: @Paul-Jan: Hans Passant often does this. Perhaps he does not have enough time and hits the rep-cap anyway. Also it's a bit incomplete, since it misses official sources. You may add an answer, give credit to Hans and enrich the basic statement by links to MSDN etc.

Comment: @Paul-Jan: If you don't want to earn reputation from such an answer, you could mark it as community wiki. IMHO it's also ok to get reputation, because you spent some additional effort for making the answer better.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was to do with using `Assembly.LoadFrom` and the current directory at start up.

The `Assembly.LoadFrom` states that it:

> assemblyFile may be absolute or relative to the **current directory**, and the assembly is loaded into the domain of the caller.

When the program is set as a start up program the current directory is
`C:\Windows\SysWOW64` for whatever reason.

As you can demonstrate by outputting `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`.

Instead of using `Assembly.LoadFrom` which does not follow the normal probing I am using `Assembly.Load` as this searches the normal directories where DLLs are contained.

> - The load context contains assemblies found by probing: in the GAC, in a host assembly store if the runtime is hosted, or in the ApplicationBase and PrivateBinPath of the application domain. Most overloads of the Load method load assemblies into this context.
> - The load-from context contains assemblies for which the user provided a path not included in the directories searched by probing. LoadFrom, CreateInstanceFrom, and ExecuteAssembly are examples of methods that load by path.

This also explains why Fusion was telling me it was only searching for DLLs in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` - as that's what `LoadFrom` does, only searches in the directory given. Which in my case was the current directory.